# How to get alternative routes' distance in Google Maps on Android v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an Android application that can display Google Maps' route and alternative routes by declaring alternatives to true. I can also get the directions for the suggested or preferred route.

However, I do not know how to get the alternative routes distance or data.

Comment: Look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Comment: @AtefHares well yeah, I did. However I did not see there if we can or cannot. It was just stated as optional. That's why I'm asking here if we can or not and how to get it

Comment: optional means that you can either request alternatives or just want to get one route. but note that as stated in the docs you will not always receive alternatives!

Comment: well yes. it is optional. What I wanted though was to get the distance of each alternative routes if it's present that is all.

Comment: OK, the `distance` JSONObject exists in the `legs` JSONArray which is in `routes` JSONArray, just like the answer below said

Comment: so you put the routes in another Arraylist

Answer (score 1):

The distance is returned in the JSON for each route that is returned.

For example, with this query to the directions api:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.6248874,-122.3708351&destination=37.7133686,-122.1712273&alternatives=true

You can see that it returns three routes, each route in a JSONObject nested in the `routes` JSONArray, and each individual route has a distance listed.

Distance for first route:

```
   "distance" : {
      "text" : "31.6 mi",
      "value" : 50831
   }
```

Distance for second route:

```
   "distance" : {
      "text" : "32.5 mi",
      "value" : 52325
   }
```

Distance for third route:

```
   "distance" : {
      "text" : "35.0 mi",
      "value" : 56271
   }
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Daniel Nugent. When I tried to display the routes though, it will only give me example: `@52131e` Why is that? How to solve this?

Comment: @NeedHelp_AndroidGoogleMap show us [edit your post] what u do and what u get!